# Can I use my voice application (Win 7) on MS Surface?

Tags: c#, tablet, speech

I developped a C#/WPF voice application on Windows 7. I use `SpeechLib` for the recognition and `System.Speech.Synthesis` for the synthesis. I do not have a tablet to test but I would like to give my application to a lucky owner of a Surface tablet.

Do you know if this application can run on Microsoft Surface? Do I need to make aditional development to be able to use the application on Surface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surface "Pro" is just like any other laptop running Windows 8. Surface "RT" is not - it runs Windows RT and is unable to run WPF applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take a look to speech reco/sytnhesis solutions on Windows RT and try to evaluate the amount of work to port my application. But I am afraid that it is a hard work...

Comment: unless you have a customer demanding RT support, you can pretty safely ignore it as sales of that OS have been quite poor

Comment: I agree with you. Potential customers will probably buy the Surface Pro  tablets which run Win 8 (and not RT). So, my application should be able to run in a professional context. But it cannot be use for a personal usage on Surface tablets with RT :(